# Error when building Mongodb on ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-server, build-error

I am trying to build mongodb (r2.4.8) with the --ssl option on a ubuntu server (13.10)

I get these errors:

```
scons --ssl --64 all

src/third_party/boost/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp: In function 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& boost::posix_time::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const boost::posix_time::time_duration&)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp:183:51: error: typedef 'std_ptime_facet' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
     typedef std::time_put<CharT>                  std_ptime_facet;
                                                   ^
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/config.hpp:57:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:48,
                 from src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp:18:
src/mongo/db/../bson/bsonobjbuilder.h: In member function 'void mongo::BSONArrayBuilder::fill(int)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:125:21: error: typedef 'boost_static_assert_typedef_836' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
          BOOST_JOIN(boost_static_assert_typedef_, __LINE__)
                     ^
src/mongo/db/../bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:836:13: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
             BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(maxElems < (BSONObjMaxUserSize/10));
             ^
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path_traits.hpp:23:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:25,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:25,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:31,
                 from src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp:20:
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214:36: error: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
                                    ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215:36: error: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
                                    ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216:36: error: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
                                    ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [build/linux2/64/ssl/mongo/shell/dbshell.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

These are just a few errors from the error list...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm works on my laptop machine, is ubuntu server somehow different from the desktop when it comes to building mongodb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually looks like a bug in boost when compiled with GCC4.8. I recently upgraded to 13.10 (desktop) and started having this exact same issue. Sure enough...

```
acron@####:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
```

Googled around a bit and found this:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7242

Easy fix is to compile with `-Wno-unused-local-typedefs`, which you can add to the scons file.

Comment: Would this go in the SConstruct file? Where in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mongodb # or monodb-server
```

You can actually trivially compile the debian package from source with a single statement:

```
apt-get source --compile mongodb
```

This tells you what Debian developers have figures out to be the required dependencies. 90% of the time this makes it quick to locate the missing bits for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this: apt-get source --compile mongodb and it works. But I still cant get scons --ssl --64 all to work on the ubuntu server. Still get the same error

Comment: looks like you run with -Werror (warnings as errors). Perhaps there is a flag in your environment (CPPFLAGS?) or the scons file? Frequently, Debian patches over build issues in their packages.

Comment: I removed the -Werror from the SConestruct and its building... One thing, is the -Werror not there for a reason ? wont the build be unstable ?

Comment: @DarkRoast It won't be more unstable than with it. Apparently the compiler has become more adept at warning about unused locals. The project devs have probably not updated their code for the latest compilers. If it's of any consolation, I get tons on -Werror-unused-local-typedefs just compiling Boost on a recent GCC. Sounds like the same deal.

Comment: Well i installed mongodb(sudo apt-get install mongodb) and then started a build with the --ssl and now it works... apt-get must have installed some dependencies I needed for the build. Thanks for all your help sehe