# End of file/pseudo-op errors compiling MongoDB with SSL

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, g++

I'm currently using MongoDB on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 with the replica set functionality across 3 sites and have gotten to the stage where I need to enable SSL. This requires compiling it myself and sadly I have no prior experience of this which is causing me some headaches.

I'm trying to compile r2.4.9 following the procedure outlined here: http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/

I have installed a ton of packages based on what I found scouring the web for related articles:

`git-core build-essential scons devscripts lintian dh-make libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libboost-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libpcap-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev rng-tools`

I also changed the SConstruct file to remove the CCFLAG `-Werror` to stop it failing immediately with so many `[-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]` as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443489/error-when-building-mongodb-on-ubuntu-server).

The compilation process seems to get quite far but always fails at the same file `dbclient_rs.cpp`:

```
g++ -o build/linux2/ssl/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -pipe -fno-builtin-memcmp -O3 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DSUPPORT_UTF8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DMONGO_SSL -DMONGO_HAVE_HEADER_UNISTD_H -DMONGO_HAVE_EXECINFO_BACKTRACE -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/libstemmer_c/include -Isrc/third_party/libstemmer_c/include -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/s2 -Isrc/third_party/s2 -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/boost -Isrc/third_party/boost -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Isrc/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Ibuild/linux2/ssl -Isrc -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/mongo -Isrc/mongo -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/s2 -Isrc/third_party/s2 -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/snappy -Isrc/third_party/snappy -Ibuild/linux2/ssl/third_party/v8/include -Isrc/third_party/v8/include src/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.cpp
```

(warning spam removed)

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:73382: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scons: *** [build/linux2/ssl/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.o] Error 4
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Note: I've also seen pseudo-op errors in the same place, but they were replaced by the above error when I removed the CCFLAG `-w` in favour of removing `Werror` instead.

Also just noticed when it starts up and does its checks the line `Checking for C library rt... no` - could this be a problem?

g++ version is 4.8.1, scons version is 2.3.0

Am I doing something unbelievably stupid here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after more searching I found the an explanation of the problem [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49245).

Seems to be related to not having enough RAM for the compilation process. I was running on a 512MB VPS. Worked fine after upgrading to 4GB (also removed the `-pipe` CCFLAG as suggested).

Comment: Had the same issue compiling on a raspberry pi. Thanks for the heads up, adding a temporary swapfile to the system pushed it past this issue and it finished building successfully.